# how to add rhel-beta repo on centos 6.2?

Tags: centos, centos6, xvfb

I want to install Xvfb on CentOS 6.2 and I added the repo refered in https://serverfault.com/questions/344793/install-xvfb-via-yum-yum-repository-for-xvfb/361304#361304. I found ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/rhel/beta/6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml is invalid now, only ...beta/7/... is valid. Can I use this repo?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to do so.
1) Install the RPM containing the repo definitions

```
$ su -c 'rpm -ivh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm'
```

2) Enable the Optional channel for your host by logging into RHN and enabling the Optional channel.  According to the EPEL wiki page this is required to resolve package dependencies.

3) Make sure EPEL and the Optional channel are enabled

```
$ yum repolist
```

Learn more about configuring EPEL at the Fedora [wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

If you prefer to configure the EPEL repo by hand, follow these steps:

1)  As root, put the following in a separate file (with a name ending in .repo) in /etc/yum.repos.d:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&amp;arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&amp;arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&amp;arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

2) import the EPEL rpm key:

```
 rpm --import https://fedoraproject.org/static/0608B895.txt
```

3) Enable the Optional channel for your host by logging into RHN and enabling the Optional channel.  According to the EPEL wiki page this is required to resolve package dependencies.

4) Make sure EPEL and the Optional channel are enabled

$ yum repolist
Thanks to my ever-present technical support person, Paul Frields, for providing the file above way back when the RHEL 6 EPEL repo RPM was not available.

Comment: epel doesn't contain Xvfb